# Wy is this code illegal in terms of variable initialization?

Tags: java, variables, initialization

```
import java.util.*;

class Example {

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Input an integer : ");
    int num = input.nextInt();
    int y;
    if (num > 100) {
      y = 200;
    }
    if (num < 100) {
      y = 200;
    }
    if (num == 100) {
      y = 200;
    }
    System.out.println(y);
  }
}
```

ERROR:

```
Example.java:19: error: variable y might not have been initialized
    System.out.println(y);

                   ^
```

Comment: If none of the `if`-branches is  entered, `y` is never initialized. Since accessing an uninitialized local variable is illegal, the compiler generates an error. The compiler is not able to infer that one of the three cases must be entered. I would recommend to use `else if` in the 2nd case and `else` in the 3rd case. This will fix the problem.

Answer (score 5):

If none of the `if`-branches is entered, `y` is never initialized. Since accessing an uninitialized local variable is illegal, the compiler generates an error (as defined in [JLS, §16](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-16.html)). The compiler is not able to infer that one of the three cases must be entered.

I recommend to use else if in the 2nd case and else in the 3rd case:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Example {

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Input an integer : ");
    int num = input.nextInt();
    int y;
    if (num > 100) {
      y = 200;
    }
    else if (num < 100) {
      y = 200;
    }
    else /* if (num == 100) */ {
      y = 200;
    }
    System.out.println(y);
  }
}
```

[<kbd>Ideone demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/SpXFJd)

Answer (score 3):

Javac does NOT flow-analysis. In other word, you know that either `num > 100`, `num < 100`, or `num == 100` is `true` but javac doesn't know.
In this case, you can combine those `if` by `else if` and `else` like that:

```java
    if (num > 100) {
      y = 200;
    } else if (num < 100) {
      y = 200;
    } else { // num == 100 must be true
      y = 200;
    }
```

You may also assign some value (eg. `0`) to `y`, but above solution is more clear.